# Fade in (ease-in) navbar background on scroll/shrink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Thus far I've been able to shrink and ease-in all elements in the navbar with the exception of the background. I've tried setting the background to an opacity of 0 before the shrink and then 1 after, however, this gives the navbar and all its children an opacity of 0 instead of just the background. The shrink in effect is absolutely perfect, but obviously seeing the navbar and all of its children on page opening is pretty important. The nav links to the right are a pretty jerky as well. When testing them locally they work to perfection, but when they're published to the web they get pretty jagged with their animations.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the webpage.

http://www.adapticpayments.com/test/home.html

Comment: place the nav elements on top of the background with pseude elements :before and :after, use position absolute and z-index.
If you set the background opacity on a parent element, the children gonna inherit the property.

Comment: Apologies for the late response but thank you so much! This worked like a charm!